# how to get direction to the shortest path outside circle in google maps android, when my current location is inside 2 or more circles?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geometry

How to get direction to the nearest location outside circle if the blue dots is the current location?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLBYl.jpg)[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLBYl.jpg)

and how to display markers ONLY around the current location in radius 2000m? I have stored the mapping lanslide in database and it displays when the app launch and it needs 7-9 seconds to load these markers. now i need to display only around the current location in order the app going smooth.

[image]

[these are the mapping dots of lanslide]

im doing my final projet, and I have a fEature which is really difficult.

Im on my android project, making a warning application on android about lanslide disaster, I do the mapping dots of lanslide locations and collect about 150 couples of lattitudes and longitudes and put it on database.

I assume if the user inside a circle, they are in lanslide location and they are not safe

the red zone radius is 2KM from the center of circle.
the orange zone radius is 1km from the center of circle.
the yellow zone radius is 500m from the center of circle

when the app is launch, the map will show up and animate the camera to my current location. 
and then the app will tell the user if they are safe or not.
if the user OUTSIDE THE CIRCLE, then the user is safe. but,
if the current location inside the circle, then the user is not safe. 
WHEN THE USER IS NOT SAFE, THE APP will give direction to shortest path outside the circle.

My app is almost done, except the last feature, I'm out of idea how to figure it out,

HOW THE APP CAN GIVE THE DIRECTION TO THE SHORTEST PATH OUTSIDE A CIRCLE??

unfortunately, how can the app will get direction to the shorthest outside circle for user if the CURRENT LOCATION inside 3 or mores circle ? and what google's libarry i can use for solve this?

how to get direction outside many circles? please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6St8.jpg)

this is my code:

public class MenuMaps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static MenuMaps instance = null;

```
private SupportMapFragment sMapFragment;
private MapView mMapView;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private String[] id, desa, status_des;
  boolean markerD[];
private Double latitude, longitude;
private Circle mCircle;
private Marker mMarker;
LatLng lokasisekarang;


boolean mapReady = false;

private GoogleApiClient client;

private GoogleApiClient client2;

public static MenuMaps getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MenuMaps();
        Log.d( "MenuMaps", "getInstance");
    }
    return instance;
}



@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)


{
    Log.d("MenuMaps", "OnCreateView");
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_maps, container, false);

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());

    mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);


        Button btnMap = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
    btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mapReady)
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        }
    }) ;


    Button btnSatellite = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnSatellite);
    btnSatellite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mapReady)
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        }
    });

    Button btnHybrid = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnHybrid);
    btnHybrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mapReady)
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        }
    });

  return inflatedView;
}

@Override

public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Menu Maps");
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mMapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}


public void getLokasi() {
    Log.d("desaStatus", "getLokasi");

    String url = "http://dharuelfshop.com/skripsi/desaStatus.php/";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("desaStatus", response);
            Gson gson = new Gson();


            try {
                JSONObject objinduk = new JSONObject(response);
                List<DesaStatus> listDesaStatus = gson.fromJson(objinduk.getString("desaStatus"), new TypeToken<List<DesaStatus>>() {
                }.getType());

                Circle circleTerdekat = null;
                Float distanceTerdekat = null;



                for (DesaStatus desaStatus : listDesaStatus
                        ) {
                    Log.d("desaStatus", desaStatus.toString());

                    LatLng center = new LatLng(desaStatus.lat_bcn,
                            desaStatus.long_bcn);

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(center)
                            .title("Desa : " + desaStatus.nama_des)
                            .snippet("Status : " + desaStatus.jenis_status)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .defaultMarker(desaStatus.kode_warna));
                    mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    CircleOptions CircleOptions =  new CircleOptions()
                            .center(center)
                            .radius(desaStatus.radius)//in meters
                            .strokeColor(Color.parseColor(desaStatus.warna_radius))
                            .strokeWidth(2)
                            .fillColor(Color.parseColor(desaStatus.warna_radius));
                    mCircle = mMap.addCircle(CircleOptions);

                    //hitung distance dan Status circle
                    float[] distance = new float[2];

                    Location.distanceBetween( lokasisekarang.latitude, lokasisekarang.longitude,
                            mCircle.getCenter().latitude, mCircle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

                    if (circleTerdekat == null) {
                        circleTerdekat = mCircle;
                        distanceTerdekat = distance[0];

                    } else {
                        if (distance[0] < distanceTerdekat ) {
                            distanceTerdekat = distance[0];
                            circleTerdekat = mCircle;
                        }
                    }

                }
                Log.d("circleTerdekat", "center: " + circleTerdekat.getCenter().latitude + " " + circleTerdekat.getCenter().longitude );

                if( distanceTerdekat > circleTerdekat.getRadius() ){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You are safe, distance from center: " + distanceTerdekat + " radius: " + circleTerdekat.getRadius(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You are not safe, distance from center: " + distanceTerdekat + " radius: " + circleTerdekat.getRadius() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }  catch (JSONException error) {
                Log.d("desaStatusError", error.toString());
            }
          }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {


        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Error woy");
            //Message
            builder.setMessage("Error " + error); //+ error diganti sama (VolleyError error)
            //Message

            //builder.setIcon()
            builder.setPositiveButton("Refreshh", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override //O nya huruf gede
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getLokasi();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });

    // menambah request ke request queue
    VolleyRequest.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    GpsTracker gps = new GpsTracker(getActivity());
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) { // gps enabled
        //Getting longitude and latitude
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        lokasisekarang = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        drawMarkerWithCircle(lokasisekarang);

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lokasisekarang, 14f));


        // \n is for new line
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else {
        // can't get location
        // GPS or Network is not enabled
        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
        //gps.stopUsingGPS();
    }
}

private void drawMarkerWithCircle(LatLng lokasisekarang) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(lokasisekarang)
            .title("You are here")
            .snippet("here")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(HUE_BLUE));
    mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(lokasisekarang)
            .radius(2000)
            .strokeWidth(2)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#500084d3"));

    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
}

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapReady = true;

    mMap = googleMap;
    getCurrentLocation();
    getLokasi();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); // buat enable button location

}}
```

Comment: This question has is irrelevant to IOS, Please remove iOS tag from question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show directions you need 2 points the origin and destination. The origin in this case will be your user's location.

Finding the destination point:

1) Currently you are storing the centre of these circular zones and their radii (500m, 1km etc). In addition to these you can easily calculate for each circle 4 'safe' points that lie along 4 directions (say N,S,E,W) and store them.

2) These points divide your circle into 4 quadrants. Now all you need to do is find which quadrant of the circle the user's current location is in and compare the distance between the points forming the quadrant and choose the lower of the two as your destination.

3) Use the Google Maps [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to show directions .

If you want to increase the accuracy of the algorithm all you need to do is increase the number of directions which will effectively divide your circle into more smaller parts and the destination will be more optimal.

Here '4' was just an arbitrary number . You can have different number based on number of safe points you choose and that will determine the accuracy of the algorithm

EDIT: Handling multiple circles intersecting is also easy. All you need to do then is instead of calculating the shortest for 1 circle you calculate for all the circles where the point lies and then find the min distance

Algorithm:

1) For each circle choose 'n' safe points. These 'n' points will form `n - 1` sectors in the circle.

2) Get the current location of the user ( say `A`) and find all the circles where this point is included.

3) For each circle where pt `A` lies, calculate sector in which it lies. Say it lies on sector formed by points `X_i` and `Y_i`. Calculate the distance `AX_i` and `AY_i`.

4) Choose the minimum across all distances `AX_i`, `AY_i` and show navigation instructions for those points

It doesn't matter if the markers appear visually close to each other.. You're not going to visually find the direction the computing device is going to do it. Lat/Long values have a very high order of precision anyway.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how i can say these '4' is the shortest location outside radius? by comparing one to another?

Comment: Yes.Actually, no matter how many directions you choose you'll only need to calculate the distance from 2 points. These will be the points forming the sector where the point lies. All other points are going to be at larger distance

Comment: thank u, Im so new on android programming, :( what google maps library I can use for this? or I just need a loop for distance-between to calculate the current location to destination point??

Comment: You can use the google maps [distance api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) for this.

Comment: yes, what if the current location is INSIDE 3 or more radius of circles which its centers is very close each other, how can I calculate these '4' points?

Comment: just like the image I atached above, the markers is very crowded

Comment: thank u, I kinda understand logically, can u show me a little example how to write in code? because Im soo neww in it

Comment: Sorry but this is not a site for doing your work. You have to be the one writing the code and if you face errors people will help you out. If you are new I suggest going through some tutorials first before trying to develop a complex application. When you do you'll find that implementing this algorithm in code is trivial.

Comment: yes i exactly know, I already writing the code. and I got stuck in these 2 features. see above i just updated my questions